# Remove vector element use the condition in vector<bool>

Tags: c++, c++11

I have two vectors a and b with the same size.

```
vector<int>  a{    4,    3,   1,    3,   1};
vector<bool> b{false,false,true,false,true};
```

I want to remove the element in `a` if the same element in `b` (the same index) is true.

After applying the function: a = 4,3,3

Note: I want to use `std` algorithms or functions instead of simple for loop.

Comment: What do you mean by using `std` instead of `for` loop?

Comment: Using std algorithms like remove, transform, etc. instead of a raw loop I imagine.

Comment: A loop would be the most _readable_.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
  std::vector<int> v {1,2,3,4,5,6};
  std::vector<bool> b {true, false, true, false, true, false};

  v.erase(std::remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), 
      [&b, &v](int const &i) { return b.at(&i - v.data()); }), v.end());
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2a613983e9069417)

Comment: Never debug while standing up http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2083debebfeb4718

Comment: @NikosAthanasiou Yeap,  you're right :) I forgot it, corrected now, thnx.

Answer (score 6):

```
void filter(std::vector<int>& v, const std::vector<bool>& b)
{
    assert(v.size() == b.size());
    auto it = b.begin();
    v.erase(std::remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), [&](int) { return *it++; }), v.end());
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/nqiDOn)

Comment: This depends on `remove_if` applying the predicate to the elements in order, which isn't guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to push the limits by not using lambdas, only `std` functions. I have two solutions but they all requires external memory:

**First solution**

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  vector<int>  a{4, 3, 1, 3, 1};
  vector<bool> b{true, false, true, false, true};
  vector<int> c;
  vector<pair<int,bool>> tmp;

  // Join                                                                       
  transform(begin(a), end(a),
            begin(b),
            back_inserter(tmp),
            make_pair<int const&,bool const&>);

  // Filter                                                                     
  auto last = partition(begin(tmp), end(tmp),
                        (bool const&(*)(std::pair<int,bool> const&))
                        std::get<1,int,bool>);

  // Copy back                                                                  
  transform(begin(tmp), last,
            back_inserter(c),
            (int const&(*)(pair<int,bool> const&))
            get<0,int,bool>);

  // Print (you could do a.swap(c) if you just want to modify 'a'
  copy(begin(c), end(c), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, ", "));
  cout << endl;
}
```

**Second solution**

It uses valarray instead:

```
  // 2nd solution using valarray                                                
  valarray<int> va(&a[0], a.size());
  valarray<bool> vb(b.size());
  copy(begin(b), end(b), begin(vb));

  valarray<int> vc( va[vb] );
  copy(begin(vc), end(vc), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, ", "));
  cout << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Without a STL algorithm, but with a modified version of `std::remove_if`:

```
template<class ForwardIt1, class ForwardIt2, class UnaryPredicate>
ForwardIt1 remove_if_tagged(ForwardIt1 first1, ForwardIt1 last1, ForwardIt2 first2,
                            UnaryPredicate p)
{
    ForwardIt1 result = first1;
    for (; first1 != last1; ++first1, ++first2) {
        if (!p(*first1, *first2)) {
            *result++ = *first1;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

std::vector<int>  a{    4,    3,   1,    3,   1};
std::vector<bool> b{false,false,true,false,true};
a.erase(
  remove_if_tagged(
    a.begin(), a.end(), 
    b.begin(), 
    [](int, bool tag) { return tag; }
  ),
  a.end()
);
```